# How to import function from c++ .dll into c sharp

Tags: c#, c++, dll

In C++ i have this function and used it like below. How to i need to code in c sharp?

```
birdRS232WakeUp(int nGroupID, BOOL bStandAlone, int nNumDevices,
WORD *pwComport, DWORD dwBaudRate, DWORD dwReadTimeout,DWORD dwWriteTimeout,int nGroupMode       
= GMS_GROUP_MODE_ALWAYS);
```

in the manual it state that "pwComport" points to an array of words, each of which is the number of the comport attached to one of the birds(e.g., COM1 = 1, COM2 = 2, etc.)

```
WORD COM_port[5] = {0,15,0,0,0}

if ((!birdRS232WakeUp(GROUP_ID,
    FALSE, // Not stand-alone
    DEVCOUNT, // Number of Devices
    COM_port, // COM Port
    BAUD_RATE, // BAUD
    READ_TIMEOUT,WRITE_TIMEOUT, // Reponses timeouts
    GMS_GROUP_MODE_ALWAYS))) 
{
    printf("Can't Wake Up Flock!\n");
    Sleep(3000);
    exit(-1);
}
```

This is how i do it in c sharp .

```
[DllImport(@"Bird.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public  static extern bool birdRS232WakeUp(int nGroupID, Boolean  bStandAlone, int      
nNumDevices,ref ushort pwComport, uint dwBaudRate, uint dwReadTimeout, uint   
dwWriteTimeout);

 ushort[] COM_port = new ushort[5]{0,13,0,0,0};

        if ((!birdRS232WakeUp(GROUP_ID, false, DEVCOUNT,ref  COM_port, BAUD_RATE, READ_TIMEOUT, WRITE_TIMEOUT)))
        {
            LWakeUpStatus.Text = "Failde to wake up FOB";

        }
```

And finalyy i got this error message "Error 2   Argument '4': cannot convert from 'ref ushort[]' to 'ref ushort'"

Someone have any clue about it?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue is that you're passing an array of type `ushort` when only a single `ushort` value is expected by your current managed extern definition:

That is:

```
ushort pwComport
```

Should be:

```
ushort[] pwComport
```

Comment: did it need add ref in front?

Comment: @LMC008: I should think so; even though arrays are reference types, it is the literal variable that is to be utilised from source in this scenario, using the `ref` keyword, AFAIK.